# 3 Arrays into 1 Array with all Combinations (code inside)

Tags: c#, arrays

I have the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{            

    string[] h = new string[2];
    h[0] = "h0";
    h[1] = "h1";

    string[] d = new string[2];
    d[0] = "d0";
    d[1] = "d1";

    string[] a = new string[2];
    a[0] = "a0";
    a[1] = "a1";  
}
```

What would be the code to generate an array containing each of the following items:

```
h0h1,h0d1,h0a1,d0h1,d0d1,d0a1,a0h1,a0d1,a0a1
```

I have been trying with nested for loops, but can't get the list of combinations above.

Comment: try with multi dimensional array of string

Comment: I don't know what language this is, but I tagged it `c#` because it looks Java-ish without being Java.

Comment: It is indeed C#, it may look otherwise because I'm fairly new to coding and using C#. Thank you for the comment, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim list as New List<string[]>
Dim result = new string[N] /* N in this case will be 9 (3^2) */
list.Add(h)
list.Add(d)
list.Add(a)

for(int i =0; i< N; i++)       
{        
    result[i] = list[Math.Truncate(i/3)][0] + list[i%3][1]
}
```

I think it's clear enough, I will extend if needed, for now:

- `list[Math.Truncate(i/3)][0]`: we get the array in the list 
  <sub>*(1st one for i:0..2, 2nd one for i:3..5 and 3nd one for i:6..8)*</sub>
  and we get its first item ([0]) value
- `list[i%3][1]`: we get the array in the list *<sub>(1st one for i:0,3,6; 2nd one for i:1,4,7; and 3nd one for i:2,5,8)</sub>* and we get its second ([1]) item's value

Then just concatenate both ítems and store them in their index

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try your solution.